# My ASP.NET Core Web API returns a value. However, my frontend is receiving an empty value with status code 200 (OK)

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm currently learning about web APIs and I'm encountering an issue that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API running in the background, and an Angular (version 15.1.5) application running in the frontend. When I call one of my API endpoints in Postman (with GET) and include a customized header, I get a response body (header itself) back as expected. However, when I make the same request from my Angular application, I receive an empty body. I am expecting the header that I passed in [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) shows in my frontend.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Postman call can be found also in the attachment

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLqOX.png)

I have attempted several troubleshooting steps to address an issue I'm encountering, but have been unable to resolve it. Specifically, I am developing an Angular application that communicates with an ASP.NET Core Web API, and I am finding that when I make a request to one of my API endpoints from my Angular application, the response body is empty, despite successful execution of the underlying code.

To further investigate the issue, I have inserted `console.log` statements into my code and have confirmed that it is running properly up to the point where the request is made. However, the response body remains empty.

I would also like to confirm whether or not a parameter passed in Postman should be visible in the frontend of my application. Additionally, I have noticed that Swagger UI is showing an empty string, which may be related to my issue.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) string to headers:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('X-CM-SSO-ACCOUNTGUID','<GUID>');

....
return this.http
      .get(this.apiEndpoint, {headers:headers, ...}
      ....
```

Comment: Thank you, '<guid>'. May I confirm whether it is possible to retrieve this information from the Postman request that I made? You can view the screenshot by clicking on the hyperlink provided above

Comment: @Delal ???  As it is written in you question , Postman request is working properly

Comment: Yes Sergey its working properly, however I want to know what you mean with '<guid>' . Maybe if its possible would you provide me the rest of the code for ssoService ?, Sorry I am still in learning phase

Comment: You have to replace <guid> with X-CM-SSO-ACCOUNTGUID parameter, for example the one you used for a Postman

Comment: Thank you!!, are you meaning that I should hardcoded in frontend ?

Comment: @Delal I don't know where you take X-CM-SSO-ACCOUNTGUID from and why do you need it, it is your problem

Comment: I apologize if my previous explanation was unclear. X-CM-SSO-ACCOUNTGUID is a header, and I have added a value in Postman("e6859fb1-7c28-4dea-ad9b-8cb08861b768" ), as indicated in the screenshot. My question is, if I pass this value in Postman, would it be visible in the frontend as well

Comment: @Delal I don't see what a Postman has to do with your application frontend.  Peope mostly use Posman  for testing APIs.

Comment: Thank you Serge, its more or less answers my question

Comment: @Delal You are welcome! If you need more help, you should ask question to how to return back X-CM-SSO-ACCOUNTGUID, but you should explain why do you need getsso action and what it should return . Maybe it makes sense to post this string into body and use Post instead of Get. We can only guess what are you trying to reach